# Java Return string from array of int's using Least Significant Bits

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve this problem and I have no idea where to start: program takes the input of an array of ints. The method needs to combine the least significant bit from each int into a sequence of binary, cast those sequences into their char equivalencies, and return the string value of the completed message.

```
public String StringsFromLeastSigBitsOfIntsSTEGO(int[] binar) {
}
```

Here are the outputs I am trying to get to:

`StringsFromLeastSigBitsOfIntsSTEGO([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]) → "Hat"`

`StringsFromLeastSigBitsOfIntsSTEGO([254, 255, 254, 254, 255, 254, 254, 254, 254, 255, 255, 254, 254, 254, 254, 255, 254, 255, 255, 255, 254, 255, 254, 254]) → "Hat"`

`StringsFromLeastSigBitsOfIntsSTEGO([188, 235, 255, 240, 154, 54, 0, 67, 12, 204, 101, 6, 0, 252, 66, 92, 6, 77, 233, 254, 8, 88, 17, 124, 4, 11, 15, 20, 24, 31, 34, 41, 44, 51, 55, 61, 64, 71, 74, 80]) → "a bet"`

Comment: Break the problem down into smaller steps.  You can get the least significant bit by using the & operator such as :   int least = some_value & 1;  You will also need to use the bitwise shift operation to group each set of 8 bits.   I would also read the [java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you need to get the least significant bit from each number and that's by as mentioned above using the & operator, once you pile up 8 bits, you can convert them to one character by parsing them with a radix of 2.
Here i am iterating over the array and saving each LSB in a string then once it is 8 bits long, it is parsed into a char.

```
public static String StringsFromLeastSigBitsOfIntsSTEGO(int[] binar)
    {
        String leastBitSequence = "";
        String ans = "";
        for (int binary : binar)
        {
            //Gets the LSB from the number and saves it in a string
            leastBitSequence += binary & 1; 
            //Check if it is 8 bit long and convert it to a char if so then empty the string
            if (leastBitSequence.length() == 8)
            {
                ans += (char) Integer.parseInt(leastBitSequence, 2);
                leastBitSequence = "";
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

**Sample Test**

```
Input: {188, 235, 255, 240, 154, 54, 0, 67, 12, 204, 101, 6, 0, 252, 66, 92, 6, 77, 233, 254, 8, 88, 17, 124, 4, 11, 15, 20, 24, 31, 34, 41, 44, 51, 55, 61, 64, 71, 74, 80};
Output: a bet
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint.

The letter `d` in ASCII in hex is 64 or 1100100 in binary.

So combining the bits going from left to right would be

```
int i = 0;

Bits in array
        |
        V

i = i + 1    i = 1;
i<<1 // shift left one bit - i = 10
i = i + 1    i = 11          
i<<1 // shift left one bit - i = 110
i = i + 0    i = 110         
i<<1 // shift left one bit - i = 1100

And so on.
```

Notice  how the value for 'd' is being build up from left to right
Now you just need to do it for all the bits.

One more hint that has been mentioned. To get the low order bit of a number, you need to
AND it (`&`) with 1.

```
3&1 = 1
2&1 = 0
13&1 =1
```